# Select or other Taxonomy Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Is there any module to support select or other option for Term reference type? I tried with select_or_other module but its not working in Term reference type

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module OR the [Simple hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/shs) for a Drupal 7 site.